# Heroku remote ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-admin-black==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e45a4b07/requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm updating my heroku by using a  django-admin-black==0.0.1, but heroku does find this version.
How can I handle this ?

```
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==3.1.6
remote:          Downloading Django-3.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-admin-black==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e45a4b07/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-admin-black==0.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e45a4b07/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: How did you install `django-admin-black` locally?

Comment: With the github link pip install git+https://github.com/app-generator/django-admin-black.git

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in your `requirements.txt` file from `django-admin-black==0.0.1` to just `git+https://github.com/app-generator/django-admin-black.git`.

This will install `django-admin-black-0.0.1`.

`requirements.txt`

```
# Get rid of this line
django-admin-black==0.0.1 

# Add this line instead
git+https://github.com/app-generator/django-admin-black.git
```